# managedObjectID throwing "Unresolved Identifier" Error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, objectid, nsmanagedobjectid

I'm trying to fetch a specific Item from the CoreData store, so that I can edit particular values for keys. The editing takes place in a different ViewController to where the entity to edit is picked.

I have `prepare(for segue:)` in the original View Controller pass the objectID for the selected entity as URL using the `uriRepresenation()` method of objectID. This is done since I could not figure out how to store the objectID as `NSManagedObjectID` (I got erros of Type mismatch)

Now that I have the URL passing between the two view controllers, the desitantion view controller has the below code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    toggleDatePicker()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    let editableObjectID = managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: editableObjectURL!)
    let editableEntity = context.object(with: editableObjectID!)
}
```

And the line:

```
let editableObjectID = managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: editableObjectURL!)
```

throws "Use of unresolved identifier "managedObjectID""

I've ran into a wall here, and can't seem to figure this one out. [The API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468882-managedobjectid) suggests this should be possible to perform but the method it references seems not to exist.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the `NSManagedObject` itself? Then there is no need to fetch it.

Comment: Whenever I try to do that, I get an error when I try to declare the Type for the variable to hold it. And since it's coming from a UITableViewCell, it's captured in a custom Cell that is using yet another View Controller. That's the only way I could think of doing it, since I'm using didSelectRow to trigger the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation:)` is a method on a persistentStoreCoordinator.  You can get the store coordinator from a managedObjectContext (the property `persistentStoreCoordinator`)

```
    let editableObjectID = context.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: editableObjectURL!)
```